# Eclipse Luna - Android app wizard hangs on at the final step

Tags: android, eclipse

On my **Mac mini OS X 10.7.4**, I have installed `Android SDK` which contains all API's up to level 19 (Android 4.4.2) onto the **/usr/local** directory (permissions set to 777) and I have Eclipse Luna (4.4.1) with ADT plugin installed and they all seem to work. When I select the 'Android Sample Project' option for platform 2.2.3 and create a Skeleton Application, it gets created and runs fine as an Android Application on my 2010 HTC Desire connected over USB debugging mode.

But when I select **Android Application Project** with those options:

```
Min required SDK: API 8: Android 2.2 
Target SDK:       API10: Android2.3.3 
Compile with:     API19: Android 4.4 
Theme:            Holo Dark

Create Activity: selected
```

The wizard hangs on after I click the finish button. The project is actually created and is available on the Package Explorer. If I return back to the first screen of the wizard, **"A project with that name already exists in the workspace"** is displayed. After I close the wizard and try to run the project as an Android Application, it contains many errors, here is the screenshot for clarity: [image]

If I repeat the same steps with the Create Activity: not selected, the wizard closes and when I run it as an Android Application it says (headers truncated for clarity)

```
Uploading Sample.apk onto device 'SH11FRT01473' 
Installing Sample.apk... Success! 
/Sample/bin/Sample.apk installed on device
Done!
```

But I **can't try or see this Sample app on my HTC device**.

Need help and advice on this. Eclipse Luna is the greatest version of Eclipse for my version of OS X. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I've noticed that the problem didn't depend on the Eclipse Luna. It was rather a problem with the Android SDK itself. Because the Android application I wanted to build was target Android2.3.3, it needed the so-called ActionBar support Library. But the Android SDK didn't contain that library and the Android SDK Manager didn't list it under the Extras folder so I had to install that library manually. I've downloaded the appropriate package from: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r21.zip into my downloads folder **~/Downloads** and installed it with:

> tar -xvf ~/Downloads/support_r21.zip --directory
>   /usr/local/android-sdk-4-0-r15/extras/android/

After that, without restarting Eclipse, I created the Android Application Project without any hang-on.